# How to load JSON to HTML table properly

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I am trying to load a JSON data to an HTML table which the desired output should look like:

[image]

but I am getting this:

[image]

Here is my attempt:

```js
var data = {
        "action":
            [
                { "id": "1001", "type": "Matrix" },
                { "id": "1002", "type": "IP Man" },
                { "id": "1003", "type": "Revenge" }
            ],
        "comedy":
            [
                { "id": "2001", "type": "Iceman" },
                { "id": "2002", "type": "Pat & Mat" },
                { "id": "2003", "type": "Sugar" }
                 ],
        "animation":
            [
                { "id": "3001", "type": "Frozen" },
                { "id": "3002", "type": "Tangled" },
                { "id": "3003", "type": "Croods" }
                 ]
    
    };
    
for (var i in data) {
  $('#result').append('<table class="table table-striped"><thead><tr><th>Id</th><th>Type</th></tr></thead><tbody class="map"></tbody></table>');
}
var tds = '<tr>';
for (var j = 0; j < data[i].length; j++) {
  var obj = data[i][j];
  tds += '<td>' + obj.id + '</td>';
  tds += '<td>' + obj.type + '</td>';
}
$('.map').append(tds);
```

```css
body {
  background: white;
}

table {
  margin: 10px;
  border: 2px solid #eee;
}

td {
  margin: 10px;
  border: 2px solid #eee;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="result"></div>
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First problem: you had opened a `tr` element, but hadn’t closed it. Second problem: you were analyzing only the last “category” (animation).

```
var data = {
  "action": [
    { "id": "1001", "type": "Matrix" },
    { "id": "1002", "type": "IP Man" },
    { "id": "1003", "type": "Revenge" }
  ],
  "comedy": [
    { "id": "2001", "type": "Iceman" },
    { "id": "2002", "type": "Pat & Mat" },
    { "id": "2003", "type": "Sugar" }
  ],
  "animation": [
    { "id": "3001", "type": "Frozen" },
    { "id": "3002", "type": "Tangled" },
    { "id": "3003", "type": "Croods" }
  ]
};

var result = $('#result');

for (var category in data) {
  result.append(
    '<table class="table table-striped"><thead>' +
    '<tr><th>Id</th><th>Type</th></tr>' +
    '</thead><tbody id="map_' + category + '"></tbody></table>'
  );

  for (var i = 0; i < data[category].length; ++ i) {
    var item = data[category][i];

    $('#map_' + category).append(
      '<tr><td>' + item.id + '</td><td>' + item.type + '</td></tr>'
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not closing off the row in the for loop.
You need to include the  and  elements in the loop too because you are adding rows, not cells.

Answer (score 0):

```js
var data = {
        "action":
            [
                { "id": "1001", "type": "Matrix" },
                { "id": "1002", "type": "IP Man" },
                { "id": "1003", "type": "Revenge" }
            ],
        "comedy":
            [
                { "id": "2001", "type": "Iceman" },
                { "id": "2002", "type": "Pat & Mat" },
                { "id": "2003", "type": "Sugar" }
                 ],
        "animation":
            [
                { "id": "3001", "type": "Frozen" },
                { "id": "3002", "type": "Tangled" },
                { "id": "3003", "type": "Croods" }
                 ]
    
    };
    

var keys = Object.keys(data);

keys.forEach((key) => {

    $('#result').append('<table class="table table-striped"><thead><tr><th>Id</th><th>Type</th></tr></thead><tbody class="map" id="'+key+'" ></tbody></table>');
 data[key].forEach((obj) =>{

  $('#'+key).append("<tr><td>"+obj.id+"</td><td>"+obj.type+"</td></tr>");
 })
})
```

```css
body {
  background: white;
}

table {
  margin: 10px;
  border: 2px solid #eee;
}

td {
  margin: 10px;
  border: 2px solid #eee;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="result"></div>
```